# How Does Eevee Handle Shader Nodes?

Tags: node-editor, development, eevee-render-engine

I have been reading about GLSL development and the applicable portion relates to how different shaders pass data between each other. As I understand it once a shader finishes the computed color, normal, depth, and any other information you specify gets passed along to the next shader. In contrast, a path tracer (Cycles) passes information which is meant to be computed later.

Does this apply to Eevee as well? Would it be possible to implement a node which extracts the color, normal, etc... information from a shader/closure/green socket connection? Or does Eevee's implementation of GLSL act more as a computation instruction pass through as opposed to a data pass through?

I'm asking because I read in Eevee's roadmap that Blender Internal material compatibility is something which they are planning on implementing. One of the features of BI which I (and much of the NPR community) find exceedingly useful is the ability to take the color and normal outputs of a material and use them in a different material, allowing for all sorts of NPR goodness. Any insight as to if this is something which would be possible in Eevee (I know it isn't in Cycles) would be greatly appreciated.